# Programming a Wifly module with PIC 16F877

Tags: wifi, pic

I am trying to get started on a project that interfaces a WiFly module (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10822)  with a PIC microcontroller (16F877). But I am really confused on how to get started with the WiFly. What (software/hardware) is needed to program the WiFly? Will I need to buy some sort of a programer to connect to my computer? Do I need to buy a WiFly shield? Sorry this is a broad question, but I can't seem to find any good starter tutorials out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a software package TeraTerm which will connect to the module and access it in command mode. This tool is similar to the hyper terminal program which shipped with windows but it is the one provided by your Wifly manufacturer. The default  settings to connect are 9600Kbps, 8 bits, No Parity, 1 stop bit.

Then you need to configure the device to your needs using certain commands. All commands are listed in http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/WiFly-RN-UM.pdf

The teraterm software and other resources can be found on http://rovingnetworks.com/resources/show/product:1

Comment: how do you connect it to your computer?